# Aside from tinting windows, is there any other way to protect a car driver from UV-A radiations?

Tags: tint

Aside from tinting windows, is there any other way to protect a car driver from UV-A radiations? I'm looking for solutions that don't involve the driver itself (e.g., I'm not looking for sunscreen, sunglasses or face mask).

If it matters, I use a Volkswagen Passat 2014.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TzFCG1
- https://redd.it/f35utk

Comment: Is this maintenance or repair?

Comment: @SolarMike no it is about improving the car. [What is our stance on questions about asking about improving a motor vehicle?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2080/1623)

Comment: @SolarMike you're welcome to write an answer or give me some pointer to it.

Comment: Here is a very useful reference: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118671603

Comment: @SolarMike sure I've just added answer. I was waiting to do the tests myself before posting an answer.

Comment: Mount a giant umbrella to the top of the vehicle.

Comment: @Moab or maybe he could drive at night...

Comment: I like your jokes. I think you should share it with skin cancer survivors, as well as the families of patients who died from skin cancer, they'll probably appreciate them.

Comment: Joking because there are no solutions other than tint.

Comment: @Moab you're welcome to write an answer stating so then

Comment: There is not an answer is not an answer, that is what comments are for.

Comment: @Moab "no" is a perfectly valid answer. "no" isn't a comment.

Comment: Disagree, and that type of answer would be flagged for removal here at SU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from  [Michael Tefts](https://www.quora.com/profile/Michael-Tefts) on https://qr.ae/TzFCG1:

> There are clear films that block so not a tint per say so you do not have to deal with illegal tinting issue on [Windscreen 36" x 15 ft. Clear UV Blocking Window Film - Weatherproofing Window Insulation Kits](https://smile.amazon.com/36-ft-Blocking-Window-Film/dp/B000KWRQA0?sa-no-redirect=1)

Answer from [Moab](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/16882/moab) posted as  [a comment on this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/74477/1623):

> There are no solutions other than tint.